# How its possible in Android same as InputAccessoryView of iOS?

Tags: android, android-keypad

i need to add extra button in android inbuilt keyboard or above keyboard it's possible in ?

can anyone suggest me any control in Android like InputAccessoryView in iOS ?

i know its possible when use/create custom keyboard but i have to add button in inbuilt android keyboard its possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button on keyboard like Done button , by setting up below property.

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Thanks , i already add these button but i need add one more button and imeOptions only add one button not more then one button so its problem....